# Pandas to_datetime show time incorrect

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I used pandas to_datetime to format timestamp for DataFrame as following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

d = {'TIMESTAMP' : Series([1294311545, 1294317813, 1294318449]),
          'PRICE' : Series([24990, 25499, 25499]),
          'VOLUME' : Series([1500000000, 5000000000, 100000000])}
df = DataFrame(d)
print df
df.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP, unit='s')
df.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)       
print df
test = df['VOLUME'].resample('H', how='sum')
print test
test2= df['PRICE'].resample('H', how='ohlc')
print test2
```

The output1 are:

```
   PRICE   TIMESTAMP      VOLUME
0  24990  1294311545  1500000000
1  25499  1294317813  5000000000
2  25499  1294318449   100000000
                     PRICE      VOLUME
TIMESTAMP                             
2011-01-06 10:59:05  24990  1500000000
2011-01-06 12:43:33  25499  5000000000
2011-01-06 12:54:09  25499   100000000
```

I second use python datetime to print out the timestamps in the above DataFrame :

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1294311545")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1294317813")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1294318449")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

The output2 are:

```
2011-01-06 02:59:05
2011-01-06 04:43:33
2011-01-06 04:54:09
```

You will find the output1 and ouput2 are different! Is this timezone issue?I need the ouput1 should be same as output2. And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromtimestamp` localizes the time if no tz is provided, you can use `utcfromtimestamp` to get what pandas does (which does not localize here)

```
In [22]: df.index[0]
Out[22]: Timestamp('2011-01-06 10:59:05', tz=None)

In [24]: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int("1294311545")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[24]: '2011-01-06 10:59:05'

In [25]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1294311545")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[25]: '2011-01-06 05:59:05'
```

If you want to localize the tz, you can do this

```
In [59]: df.index = df.index.tz_localize('Asia/Shanghai').tz_convert('UTC')

In [60]: df
Out[60]: 
                           PRICE      VOLUME
TIMESTAMP                                   
2011-01-06 02:59:05+00:00  24990  1500000000
2011-01-06 04:43:33+00:00  25499  5000000000
2011-01-06 04:54:09+00:00  25499   100000000
```

Comment: df.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP, unit='s') this line is a must for me, how to fix this timezone issue with pandas and DF?

Comment: you result is in UTC, what do you want to do with it? you can ``tz_localize`` if you want, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-zone-handling)

Comment: I updated my post. I use pandas for financial OHLC process, the timestamp is used as DF's index. pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP, unit='s')  is a MUST for my application.

Comment: and what tz are these epoch seconds coming from?

Comment: The TIMESTAMP is queried from database and returned as JSON data. No tz is provided.

Comment: I put an example of what you need to do to localize. but what exactly is the problem? the python code ``fromtimestamp`` DOES localize a number that is probably already local, so its wrong. pandas does the right thing here.

Comment: I need the output1 to be exactly same as output2 which is right for me. Do you mean formtimestamp output is wrong, but pandas output is right here?

Comment: ``fromtimestamp`` localized to the current timezone whatever it is. pandas does not. what timezone do you really want?

Comment: China Beijing timezone, should be UTC +8:)

Comment: you are a hero! The last question:"2011-01-06 02:59:05+00:00" could be changed to "2011-01-06 02:59:05"? I'm a newbie to both python and pandas:)

Comment: ``df.index.tz = None`` to de-localize

Comment: Works perfectly~ Thanks so much for your quick and great help!